# Hello, neophyte user looking to solve this script error: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatting

Here's my script, it works in codecademy.com but not on python shell, which worries me because there's no point learning code if I can't use it in python. Here's a list of commands I spiced up from one of the lessons:

```
Name = input("What is your name traveller? ")
Sex = input("Are you Male or Female? ")
Age = input("How old are you in years? " ) 
Race = input("What Race are you? - (Human / Elf / Halfling) ")

print("Ah so your name is %s, you are a %s year old %s, who was born an %s") % (Name, Age, Sex, Race)
```

the error consists of the string formatting at the bottom which isnt working with python 3.4, could anyone explain why its not working?

Comment: First - you have a stray appostraphe at the end of the first line which is causing the code to format badly here (and if it's in your real code, might be causing an error). Second - could you add the exact error message to your answer?

Comment: The actual problem is that your last line should be `print("Ah so your name is %s, you are a %s year old %s, who was born an %s" % (Name, Age, Sex, Race) )` - that I've moved the % and formatting arguments into the bracket.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `'` on line one - the SO syntax highlighting shows it clearly.

As for the print statement, you're trying to perform `% (Name, Age, Sex, Race)` on the returned value of calling `print`. Instead, try

```
print "Ah so your name is %s, you are a %s year old %s, who was born an %s" % (Name, Age, Sex, Race)
```

for Python 2, or

```
print("Ah so your name is {}, you are a {} year old {}, who was born an {}".format(Name, Age, Sex, Race))
```

for Python 3.

Comment: that was a typo, the error message is :
>>> print("Ah so your name is %s, you are %s year old %s, who was born an %s") % (Name, Age, Sex, Race)
Ah so your name is %s, you are %s year old %s, who was born an %s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#53>", line 1, in <module>
    print("Ah so your name is %s, you are %s year old %s, who was born an %s") % (Name, Age, Sex, Race)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
print("Ah so your name is %s, you are a %s year old %s, who was born an %s") % (Name, Age, Sex, Race)
```

with:

```
print("Ah so your name is %s, you are a %s year old %s, who was born an %s" % (Name, Age, Sex, Race))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Don't need %s - also a typo

You tope an extra (') after your first line - typo.
You don't need to use %s - just do this (use input):

```
Name = input("What is your name traveller?\n ")
Sex = input("Are you Male or Female?\n ")
Age = input("How old are you in years?\n ") 
Race = input("What Race are you? - (Human / Elf / Halfling)\n ")

print("So your name is " + Name, ", you are " + Sex, ", you are " + Age, 
"and you are a/an " + Race, ".")
```